# Where can I train two handed weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I train two handed weapons. I can't find the trainer anywhere.
Is there a wiki or anything listed with the available trainers?

Comment: The companions building in Whiterun (starts with a J... big building on 2nd tier, to the east side of town) has someone in there I believe. I don't recall their name, will update later(ie: create answer) once I am at home on pc and can get names/verify

Comment: the companion's name is Vilkas I believe

Answer (score 3):

There are two trainers for two-handed weapons:

- **Torbjorn Shatter-Shield** in Windhelm is an expert trainer. You can find him in the House of Clan Shatter-Shield.
- **Vilkas** in Whiterun is a master trainer. You can find him the Jorrvaskr living quarters (i.e. the Companions' Headquarters)

Note there is no journeyman trainer for two-handed weapons, like many of the other skills.

**Addendum:** The strategy guide confirms there are only two trainers, and no journeyman trainer.

Comment: Are you sure there are no journeyman trainers? I'm just curious if this was from a strategy guide or if you've been tracking it personally.

Comment: @JClaspill Personal research plus confirmation from searching online. Can't really prove a negative: if there happens to be a Journeyman trainer that nobody's found (would be pretty amazing, since all the others have been found), I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can train in sneak/archery/one-handed/two-handed kind of fast by activating the warrior stone and attacking one of the two NPCs that you were supposed to visit in the beginning of the game.

I leveled my sneak and one handed up all at once one day just by doing that repeatedly, I even started on two handed and archery but archery took longer.